# Issue with using Greater Than or Equal to

Tags: zapier

So I have tried this a number of ways but every time I have someone score above 80 it returns Failed and not Passed...

First Way:

```
if (inputData.score >= '80') {
  return {result: 'Passed'};
} else {
  return {result: 'Failed'};
}
```

Second Way:

```
if (inputData.score >= '80') {
  output = 'Passed';
} else {
  output = 'Failed';
}

return {result: output};
```

However, if someone gets 80 it will return a Pass... I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Tried removing single-quotes from `'80'`? You are checking a string against greater-than operator.

```
if (inputData.score >= 80) {
  return {result: 'Passed'};
} else {
  return {result: 'Failed'};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You definitely want to be comparing numbers to numbers. As the other answerer mentions, convert your incoming score to a number and compare it to a number.

```js
if (parseInt(inputData.score, 10) >= 80) {
  return {result: 'Passed'};
} else {
  return {result: 'Failed'};
}
```

As for which of the two return methods to use, they're equal as far as Zapier is concerned. I find the first a little cleaner, so I went with that.